# Powershell - Declare empty array of Objects with size

Tags: powershell

How can I declare an empty array of Objects in Powershell and specify the size?

I basically want to do convert this C# code to Powershell:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```powershell
$objects=New-Object Object[] 5
```

or

```powershell
$objects=[Array]::CreateInstance([Object],5)
```